# Menu above metaslider after scrolling back and forth

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

For context I'm using zerif-lite template, so, my menu follows the roll of the page.

When I access in the first moment, everything is normal, but when I scrolling down and back, the metaslider stay back my menu.

See here http://i3inovacoes.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials and research I found the answer.

Entering the front page.php and paste metaslider code after " <- Home Section / END -> "

It was all I had to do